# How to install ARCore on Android Studio emulators to test SceneForms Sample application?

Tags: android, emulation, arcore, sceneform

**Problem**: I'm attempting to run the SceneForms sample applications on the Android Studio Emulator [SceneForms Samples Link](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart). This requires the Latest ARCore application which must be downloaded from the Google Play Store.

- Attempt 1: The latest emulator image that Android Studio has with
  Google Play Store is the Google Nexus 5X. Unfortunately I recieve a
  *This device isn't compatible* when trying to install. [Nexus 5X unable to install ARCore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wqqE.png)
- Attempt 2: None of the Pixel 2 images have Google Play Store.
- Attempt 3: I attempt to grab ARCore latest apk from here and install
  on the device but the emulator won't allow me to install.
  https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases

Could anyone else attempt to run this sample application on an emulator and give me advice? I doubt this is a hardware issue as I have good GPU and CPU (R9 290/i7 4790k)

Comment: Have you read this ?https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator

Comment: @PunitVara Yes. Although this is unrelated as I can't even install ARCore to test this. Also this instructions ask for Pixel 2, which was mentioned in my post :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your emulator is configured to use the latest version of OpenGL ES:

Click More in the running emulator's toolbar.
**Select Settings > Advanced > OpenGL ES API level > Renderer maximum (up to OpenGL ES 3.1).**
Restart the emulator. When prompted, do not save the current state.

After restarting the emulator, briefly interact with the emulated deivce, then check whether OpenGL ES 3.0 or higher is being used by grepping the device logs:

```
adb logcat | grep eglMakeCurrent
```

If you see ver 3 0 or higher version, then you can run Sceneform apps in the emulator:

```
… …  …  … D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebe63540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd104cb40)
```

If you see a lower version, then your desktop GPU does not support OpenGL ES 3.0 and you must instead use a [physical supported device](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)

*For example, MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) support OpenGL 2 only*

Comment: Yes, I've done this. Unrelated to doing being able to install ARCore. Could you try to install yourself?

Comment: @OhHeyImBri I receive an error "This device does not support AR" on the Play Market page. I think this is why it happens.

Comment: Thank you for trying. It appears no emulators work for thia development. Only physical devices :(